# Vertically centering a title page

Tags: latex, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertically center a title on a custom-sized page with latex. I've written the following code, but for some reason it doesn't center. Could someone please point me to what's wrong with it?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{88.184mm}
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{113.854mm}

\usepackage[margin=0.5cm, paperwidth=88.184mm, paperheight=113.854mm]{geometry}

\title{[[title]]}
\date{[[date]]}
\author{[[author]]}

\begin{document}
    \vspace{\fill}
    \maketitle
    \vspace{\fill}

    \newpage

    [[text]]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There are two small bugs in your code.

First, if you want the `\vspace` to work at the beginning or end of a page, you should use the starred version (`\vspace*`).

This would work, but `\maketitle` is a pretty complicated macro, and if used like in your example, it just puts the title at the second page. You can use the `titlepage` environment, which gives you much more command over how the title page looks like -- including the spacing. For example, you could use the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{88.184mm}
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{113.854mm}

\usepackage[margin=0.5cm, paperwidth=88.184mm, paperheight=113.854mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{center}
      {Huge [[title]]}\\[0.5cm]
      {Large [[author}\\[0.4cm]
      [[date]]
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{\fill}
  \end{titlepage}

  [[text]]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 21):

```
\null  % Empty line
\nointerlineskip  % No skip for prev line
\vfill
\let\snewpage \newpage
\let\newpage \relax
\maketitle
\let \newpage \snewpage
\vfill 
\break % page break
```

Comment: This is excellent. I have created approximately 50 documents (which were relatively important) and used this code; worked every time.

Comment: Even better is to wrap this into `\newenvironment{centervertically}{before}{after}`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make everything work even with `\maketitle` put your `\vspace*{\fill}` inside the first and the last attribute, exp:

```
 \title{**\vspace*{\fill}**[[title]]}

 \date{[[date]]}

 \author{[[author]]**\vspace*{\fill}**[[}

 \begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \newpage

   [[text]]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

As in the answer by finrod, `\maketitle` *is a pretty complicated macro*, this is why I didn't feel like overwriting it myself (`\renewcommand\maketitle{`...). Nevertheless, copying, pasting and editing lines 170-201 of [article.cls documentclass](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=markup), I could add a new one to customize (`\newcommand\mymaketitle{`...) as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{88.184mm}
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{113.854mm}

\usepackage[margin=0.5cm, paperwidth=88.184mm, paperheight=113.854mm]{geometry}

\title{Title}
\date{Date}
\author{Author}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mymaketitle{%
  \begin{titlepage}
    \null\vfil\vskip 40\p@
    \begin{center}
      {\LARGE \@title \par}
      \vskip 2.5em
      {\large \lineskip .75em \@author \par}
      \vskip 1.5em
      {\large \@date \par}
    \end{center}\par
    \@thanks
    \vfil\null
  \end{titlepage}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mymaketitle

Text
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: screenshot of output]